# ARFrame retrieved with captureHighResolutionFrame() has different field of view

Tags: ios, arkit, realitykit

When capturing an HD image from `ARSession` with `captureHighResolutionFrame()` (and `capturedImage`) the boundaries of that frame's image do not match the boundaries that you'd get with an image created from `ARFrame.currentFrame`. For some reason the HD image has smaller field of view.

Here's an example of the difference. The top image is captured with the captureHighResolutionFrame() and the bottom one is taken from `currentFrame`. The difference is very small but you can see the difference in top and bottom parts of the images clearly.

[image]

The problem comes when we absolutely want to capture fully what is being previewed and the HD image gets cropped. Also because of this cropping we have some anchors we're converting from real word coordinates that are offset.

Any ideas why the HD frame is not the same as the current frame?

**Update**

This seems to be an issue with only some devices. It is reproducible with iPhone 12 mini, but not with iPhone 8 Plus or iPhone 15 Pro.